# Mapbox Android - How to access vector tile data given a bouding zone and zoom lvl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I am working on a custom renderer an I want to access vector tile data to retrieve the features geometry from :

- the offline dataset in priority
- then a fallback on the cache
- then a fallback to the Mapbox servers.

So given the bounding coordinates and a zoom level, how can I access the data ?

Answer (score 0):

> So given the bounding coordinates and a zoom level, how can I access the data ?

There is [Mapbox Vector Tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-vector-tiles) (here is a sample query: [http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/14/4823/6160.mvt?access_token={your_access_token}](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/14/4823/6160.mvt?access_token=%7Byour_access_token%7D)).

This [specification](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Implementations) describes how lng/lat can be converted to tile numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this method, but I wonder if it works with offline data.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had failed to find any mention of this in https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/android/maps/api/9.5.0/